# rowfilter error: Missing operand after ''%اح%'' operator

Tags: c#, rowfilter, operand

I dont know why I have below error:

```
Missing operand after ''%اح%'' operator.
```

on

```
dv.RowFilter = "[customer] LIKE N'%" + value + "%'";
```

also I changed code to:

```
dv.RowFilter = "[customer] LIKE N'%" + value.Replace(@"'", "''") + "%'";
```

but still I have error.

**Note:** *I used alias for column name of table. so "customer" is alias*

Comment: What's the 'N' in your string represent? If you do away with it, I'm sure it will work.

Comment: if the type of field be Nvarchar, I should use 'N' before data

Comment: This looks like you're using a DataView and NOT SQL. The N prefix is for SQL. Get rid of the N prefix because you don't need it.

Comment: Must mean something is strange about what is in the variable `value`. What are you passing in value?

Comment: I solved it :D I missed single cot before % :D

Comment: if you fixed it, please respond to the question saying what you've done and mark it as answered.

Comment: @Reza Shirazian hi! how are u? I wanna learn lambda in list. do you know any useful ebook or web site to offer me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if type of field is NVARCHAR, you shouldn't use "N" in C# codes.

```
dv.RowFilter = "[customer] LIKE '%" + value + "%'";
```